# How to perform spectral inversion in the frequency domain to convert a low-pass filter into a high-pass filter?

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, filter-design, digital-filters

To convert a linear-phase FIR low-pass filter into a high-pass filter with the same cut-off frequency, we can invert the sign of the low-pass filter's impulse response $h(n)$ and then add one to the center point: $\delta(n)-h(n)$, where the $\delta(n)$ is the unit impulse function.

I am trying to verify the result in the frequency domain. If the DFT of $h(n)$ is $H(f)$, then the DFT of $\delta(n)-h(n)$ is $1-H(f)$. However, in MATLAB it seems that I cannot generate the desired high-pass filter kernel by applying the `ifft()` function to $1-H(f)$. The unit impulse function is added to the first point of the high-pass filter kernel instead of the center point. What is the reason for this and how can I correct my code?

[image]

MATLAB code to generate this figure:

```
%% Generate window-sinc filter coefficients
% CutOffFreq and TransBandWidth should be expressed as fractions of sampling rate between 0 and 0.5.
CutOffFreq = 0.1;
TransBandWidth = 0.01;

% Approxiately calculate the filter order (must be a even integer).
M = 4 / TransBandWidth;
M = round((M-2)/2)*2+2; % Round to the nearest even integer

% Generate the sinc function. Filter length = filter order + 1.
idx = 0:1:M;
Sinc = sin(2*pi*CutOffFreq*(idx-M/2)) ./ (idx-M/2);
Sinc(M/2+1) = 2 * pi * CutOffFreq;  % Solve the divided by zero problem

% Generate the Blackman window.
BlackMan = 0.42 - 0.5*cos(2*pi*idx/M) + 0.08*cos(4*pi*idx/M);

% Generate the filter coefficients (the impulse response function).
b = Sinc .* BlackMan;

% Normalized the filter coefficients to have unity gain at DC.
b = b / sum(b);

%% Spectral inversion in the frequency domain
bfft = fft(b);
b1 = ifft(1-bfft);

figure('Color','w');
plot(b,'Color','b','LineWidth',1);
hold on;
plot(b1,'Color','m','LineWidth',1);
xlim([-1,length(b)+1]);
legend({'Low-pass filter kernel','Wrong high-pass kernel'});
```

Comment: shift your unit impulse to the middle of the filter.

Comment: For a circuit representation of a filer, one point to remember is if you define an output in one place it can be low-pass, and another output is high-pass.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw in your logic is assuming that the frequency response of your lowpass filter in its passband is identically $1$. You're inherently assuming this when thinking that you can form the highpass filter by simply calculating $H_{hp}(f) = 1 - H_{lp}(f)$.

However, the lowpass filter has *group delay* because the peak of the sinc function doesn't occur at $n = 0$. Instead, as a symmetric FIR filter, it will have a delay of $\frac{N}{2}$ samples, where $N$ is the filter order. This means that the frequency response of the filter across the passband may have unity *magnitude*, but it will have *linear phase*! Recall the [time shift property of the discrete-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Properties):

$$
x[n-k] \Leftrightarrow X(f)e^{-j2\pi fk}
$$

So, instead of your prototype lowpass filter having a response of $1$ in the passband, it actually has a response of $e^{-j2\pi fk}$, which imparts a phase shift that is linearly proportional to frequency. If you would like to transform this filter to a highpass structure with equivalent group delay, you would need to take this into account when synthesizing your highpass filter in the frequency domain:

$$
H_{hp}(f)= e^{-j2\pi f\frac{N}{2}} - H_{lp}(f)
$$